# Limit of a function that 'swings too much'

Tags: calculus, limits

I am learning limits and I see tons of examples like this where a function fluctuates a lot closer to the origin and is thus said to have no limit at $x=0$.

However, since we are able to draw a continuous line even through the fluctuations, isnt this just a function, thats just really zoomed out? Like if we were to zoom in very, very close to 0, wouldnt it look like a curve of just $sin(x)$ and thus continuous near 0 with left and right limits?

Why would a function that can be drawn with a continuous line (as shown in the image) *not* have a limit?

[image]

Comment: It is not a matter of zoom, you'll observe similar oscillation regardless of the scale in the graphic. This function does not approach a specific value as $x$ tends to zero.

Comment: This continuous line would have infinite length inside a finite rectangular view. In any case, that's not the actual definition of continuous...

Comment: To be fair, the explanation in the screenshot is not great and "a graphing utility" is certainly not suitable to determine whether a limit exists or not.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you zoom in it *doesn't* look like $\sin x$. Remember that $\sin x$ hits zero every time $x$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$, so $\sin \frac{\pi}{x}$ will hit zero every time $\frac{\pi}{x}$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$, which will happen when $x = 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, \ldots$ - in other words, the zeros of the function get closer and closer together. At the same time, when $\frac{1}{x}$ is half-way between integers (i.e. when $x = \frac{2}{3}, \frac{2}{5}, \ldots$), the function will hit $\pm 1$. And as $x$ approaches zero, you're going to find the function oscillating faster and faster, so that no matter how much you zoom in you're still going to see a function that covers every possible value between $-1$ and $+1$.

And as much as it looks like the function is completely continuous, let me ask you - what value does it take at $x = 0$?

Comment: so the function is indeed undefined for $x=0$ i agree. however, isnt there a limit from both left and right? I mean sure it fluctuates a ton, but there *has* to be forward continuous movement right since as the diagram shows you are able to make lines going up and down. arent the points on those lines continuous? or is there something more fundamental about continuity i am not getting?

Comment: The function is continuous everywhere *except* at $x = 0$, and the limit can't exist because there's no single meaningful value you can give it. There is a much stricter definition of limits that you won't encounter until much later on, but it boils down to whether getting closer to the limit point forces the function into a smaller and smaller range, and for this function every interval $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ still contains values of $f(x)$ that cover the full range of $[-3, 3]$, and it never narrows down.